# Draw a status bar with text in itext PdfPCell

Tags: java, pdf, graphics, itext, 2d

Trying to create/draw a status bar in a PdfCell. (it will be show up in multipile pages in multiple table with different values.)

Should I create an image in memory and set that in the cell? 
If I want to do that, how to create image in memory and send that to iText. All the samples I see is feeding from a file....

Can iText library help with actually making the status bar with all the text and extra line around it. (extra long line at both end.. number 0 on top of first line, number 1000 on top of last line... center text to show the status "750/1000"... )

Thanks for any idea.

Adding more info..
Here is the code I try so far. No idea how to do center text between 2 cell (setPaddingTop to push to lower cell did not do the trick...) .
Also I use indent to get the text on top of lines. Any idea to improve the code are welcome.

```
PdfPTableExt innerTable = new PdfPTableExt();

int finalScore = 750;
//PdfPTableExt rectTable = new PdfPTableExt(new int[] {1,1,1,1});
PdfPTableExt rectTable = new PdfPTableExt(new int[] {500,finalScore,1000-finalScore,500});

// Draw cell for padding and number     
Paragraph startParagraph = new Paragraph("0");      
startParagraph.setIndentationLeft(82);
PdfPCellExt startCell = new PdfPCellExt();
startCell.addElement(startParagraph);
startCell.setFixedHeight(25);
rectTable.addCell(startCell);   

PdfPCellExt topMiddle = new PdfPCellExt();
topMiddle.setColspan(2);

Paragraph middleParagraph = new Paragraph(Integer.toString(finalScore));    
middleParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
middleParagraph.setPaddingTop(30);
topMiddle.addElement(middleParagraph);        
rectTable.addCell(topMiddle);   

Paragraph limitParagraph = new Paragraph("1000");
limitParagraph.setIndentationLeft(-15);    
PdfPCellExt limitCell = new PdfPCellExt();
limitCell.addElement(limitParagraph);
rectTable.addCell(limitCell);

rectTable.completeRow();

PdfPCellExt middle1 = new PdfPCellExt();
middle1.setFixedHeight(25);
middle1.setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
middle1.setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.BLACK);    
rectTable.addCell(middle1);     

// Draw Rect
PdfPCellExt middle2 = new PdfPCellExt();
Paragraph numParagraph = new Paragraph("750");
numParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
middle2.addElement(numParagraph);       

middle2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.ORANGE);
rectTable.addCell(middle2);    

PdfPCellExt middle3 = new PdfPCellExt();
middle3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
rectTable.addCell(middle3);        

PdfPCellExt middle4 = new PdfPCellExt();
middle4.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
middle4.setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.BLACK);    
rectTable.addCell(middle4);         

    rectTable.completeRow();

// Draw empty cell for bottom padding rects
PdfPCellExt bottom1 = new PdfPCellExt();
bottom1.setFixedHeight(25f);
rectTable.addCell(bottom1);
PdfPCellExt bottom2 = new PdfPCellExt();
rectTable.addCell(bottom2); 
PdfPCellExt bottom3 = new PdfPCellExt();
rectTable.addCell(bottom3);    
PdfPCellExt bottom4 = new PdfPCellExt();
rectTable.addCell(bottom4);    
rectTable.completeRow();        

PdfPCellExt rectCell = new PdfPCellExt();      
rectCell.addElement(rectTable);
innerTable.addCell(rectCell);
```

PdfPCellExt is just a wrapper class

```
public class PdfPCellExt extends PdfPCell{
    public PdfPCellExt() {
    super();
    this.setPadding(PdfPadding.None);
    this.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain why [the example](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-5#2962-c05e14_jekyllhydetablev7.java) from [chapter 5 of the tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) doesn't work for you. Look at the [screen shot](https://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/C05F19.png) and explain how your requirement is different in case I misunderstood the question. Never post a question on Stack Overflow without code. Read the tutorials if you don't know where to start.

Comment: Note that the class `PdfCell` is an inner class of a version of iText dating from the stone age. iText 5 had a class named `PdfPCell`, but support for iText 5 has been discontinued in favor of support for iText 7. The example mentioned in my previous comment also exists for iText 5 though. It was an example in the second edition of the "iText in Action" book I wrote in 2009. Your description in words is hard to understand and should be replaced by a (hand-drawn or PPT-created) image. Creating an image in memory is easy, but totally unnecessary if you just need a monochrome rectangle.

Comment: Please improve your question based on the comments above. Describe the problem, *not* your interpretation of how the problem should be solved. You don't need an image to create a status bar; it's much more elegant to draw paths and shapes (vector data, not a raster image), even (and especially) if you want the status bar to have a gradient color.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. The example give me some idea. I still have no idea how to put text around the edge of cell or center between 2 cells. I add my sample code here for reference. Thanks

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46936653/1729265) a step into the desired direction?

Comment: Thanks mkl. The example helps a lot. I am still not sure about the text layout. on top of the bar. Is there a good way to put centered text on top of the cell line. (I kind of cheated using  setIndentationLeft(-15) )